# PHP , Mysql , searching inside database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to return all the rows from a specific table when a specific column value is contained in a PHP variable, e.g : row 34: has column 'xyz' value equal to = "rabbit" and my php variable is `$var = "rabbit,robert,teen"`, and because the "xyz" column value is contained in `$var` I want it to be selected.

How can I do that?

Comment: change it to the equivalent of WHERE xyz IN (rabbit,robert,teen)

Comment: @Cups: He may not want `robert` and `teen`.  Or does he?

Comment: I don't have any thing with robert and teen , but because rabbit is in the php variable and xyz column is rabbit I want the column to be returned.

Comment: @CioroianuDenisGabriel: But there are other things in the variable too, how do you know you only want `rabbit`?  Does Cups' suggestion of `WHERE xyz IN($var)` work for you?

Comment: no it doesn't , I get (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%,Romania,Germany,United States of America%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5' at line 1) error when I run it with that code.

Comment: @Rocket: He's suggesting that if there *were* "robert" and "teen" entries in the table, he would want them, but for the purposes of this example there are not.

Answer (score 2):

convert the comma separated list to sql format and place in the query

```
$query = "select blah blah WHERE xyz IN ('".str_replace("," ,"','", $var)."');"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
$arr = explode(',', $var);
$where_in_val = '';
foreach($arr as $value){
  $where_in_val.= "'$value',";
}
$where_in_val = substr($where_in_val,0,-1);
```

Then your query might be something like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE xyz IN ($where_in_val)
```

Note: Don't forget cleaning/escaping/sanitizing the user's input.